# Visual Studio 2010 : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol : sapi.h and Microsoft Speech SDK for KINECT

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compiler-construction, sapi, lnk2001

I'm encountering a strange bug in Visual Studio 2010...

I work with the Kinect for Windows SDK v1.8 on VS 2010 Ultimate, for a speech recognizer program using the MS Kinect.

Like it's explained in the sample SpeechBasics (available on Kinect Developer Toolkit Browser), I added the specifics VC++ include and library paths into my project properties, before listing the default system include and library directories.

But When I buid the solution,  I get the following errors :

> CKinect_Squeletton.obj: error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SPDFID_WaveFormatEx
>   CKinect_Squeletton.obj: error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _CLSID_SpStream
>   CKinect_Squeletton.obj: error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _CLSID_SpInprocRecognizer
>   CKinect_Squeletton.obj: error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol     _CLSID_SpObjectTokenCategory
>
> build failed.

I had checked all my include files, all my project properties. I did a lot of research, and tested many possibilities of response, but I hadn't found response for my problem...

I have tried cleaning the solution, build with a x64 target architecture, but that doesn't always work.

- Why have I this problem ?

Comment: Have you checked http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1ba15d2a-f76f-42bf-bd49-fc01ad32a4de/error-while-running-sample-code-on-speech-sdk-built-using-platform-builderwince-50?forum=vssmartdevicesnative ?

Comment: Project + Properties, Linker, Input.  You need to add `sapi.lib` to the Additional Dependencies setting.  Or use `#pragma comment(lib, "sapi.lib")` in your source code.

Answer (score 0):

Like suggested in the comment, I've checked the [link on social MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1ba15d2a-f76f-42bf-bd49-fc01ad32a4de/error-while-running-sample-code-on-speech-sdk-built-using-platform-builderwince-50?forum=vssmartdevicesnative)

I've resolved some errors but not all in using `__uuidof(SpStream)` instead of `CLSID_SpStream` , and `__uuidof(SpInprocRecognizer)` instead of `CLSID_SpInprocRecognizer` .

But i don't found `CLSID_SpObjectTokenCategory` in my code, I have only

```
ISpObjectToken *pEngineToken = NULL;
hr = SpFindBestToken(SPCAT_RECOGNIZERS,L"Language=40C;Kinect=True",NULL,&pEngineToken);
```

I can't replace it with `__uuidof(SpObjectTokenCategory)` .

Also, I always don't know how to resolve the error

```
CKinect_Squeletton.obj: error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SPDFID_WaveFormatEx
```

I've added sapi.lib in Project + Properties, Linker, Input, and I also try with `#pragma comment(lib, "sapi.lib")`

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my problem !

I work on Windows 7 64bit, and I had installed MS Speech Platform SDK 11 x64.

But to build with a x86 target architecture , I had to install and use MS Speech Platform SDK 11 x86, and specify in my project properties the path for the x86 sapi lib !

The compiler gave me errors when I've tried to build with a x64 target architecture, because others specific libraries that I have included in the project are for a x86 architecture...

Sorry and maybe this solution will help someone one day !